# How do I Create objects and save with core data in for loop instead of overwriting each time?

Tags: swift, for-loop, core-data, insert

I am trying to use a for loop to create objects, which have attributes I will use later to populate a map. I am able to loop through and populate the attributes of the object, but when I save the object, it seems to be overwriting each time. the for loop pulls data out of my firebase database.

```
let holes = [hole1,hole2,hole3,hole4,hole5,hole6,hole7,hole8,hole9,hole10,hole11,hole12,hole13,hole14,hole15,hole16,hole17,hole18]
                for hole in holes {

                    let holeX = hole?["HoleX"] as? Double // these are just grabbing the data for the appropriate hole from my firebase data. 
                    let holeY = hole?["HoleY"] as? Double
                    let holeH = hole?["HoleH"] as? Double
var newHole = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "HoleCoordinateData", into: self.managedObjectContext)
                    newHole.setValue(holeX, forKey: "HoleX")
                    newHole.setValue(holeY, forKey: "HoleY")
                    newHole.setValue(holeH, forKey: "HoleH")
                    newHole.setValue(holeNumber, forKey: "holeNumber")
                    newHole.setValue("\(holeNumber)", forKey: "holeNumberString")
  self.managedObjectContext.insert(newHole)

                    holeNumber += 1
 }
                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()

                } catch {
                    print("Could not save Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
```

I have tried the do try catch within the for loop. I originally had the newHole being initialized prior to the for loop, but I put it inside on the advice of some other stack questions and responses. I originally filled out `newHole` by just doing `newHole.holeX = holeX`. obviously some of these changes were just different ways of doing the same thing, but I've been spinning my wheels on this for long enough to try anything I could.